# $\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{\sin{x}}\sin{2x}}{x^a}dx$ convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have to check the following: When does integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{\sin{x}}\sin{2x}}{x^a}dx$ converges?
In my opinion, this converges for $a>0$ by Dirichlet's test, otherwise diverges. Am I correct?

Also, when does integral from $\int_0^\infty $ of the same function  absolutely converges? I got that it diverges for every $a$. Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your conclusion to the first question is correct, but you did not show how you applied the Dirichlet's test. The conclusion to the second question is not correct. BTW you forgot $dx$ in the integral.

Comment: @user $\int_1^M e^{\sin{2x}}dx$ is finite and $x^{-a}$ monotonically decreases to zero. I forgot word "absolutely"-integral absolutely diverges, is that correct?

Comment: That's wrong. $\int_1^M e^{\sin x} dx$ is not bound. You should include the factor $\sin2x$ as well. Can you prove that in the latter case the integral is bound?

Comment: Do you ask about the absolute convergence of the integral from 1 to infinity or from 0 to infinity?

Comment: @user I made a typo, $\int_1^M e^{\sin{x}}\sin{2x}dx$ is finite. I ask about absolute convergence from 0 to infinity.

Comment: The second integral converges absolutely if $1 <a <2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Indeed for $f(x)=e^{\sin x}\sin2x$ we have for any $M>1$
$$
\left|\int_1^M f(x)dx\right|=\left|2\int_1^M  e^{\sin x}\sin x\, d(\sin x)\right|=
\left|\Big[2(\sin x- 1)e^{\sin x}\Big]_1^M\right|\le 4e
$$
and for $a>0$:
$$
g(x)=\frac1{x^a}>0,\quad g'(x)=-\frac a{x^{a+1}}<0.
$$

Thus $\int_1^\infty f(x)g(x) dx$ converges by Dirichlet's test.

For $a\le0$ the integral diverges since $f(x)g(x)$ does not converge to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

What conncerns the second question
the integral $\int_0^\infty|f(x)g(x)|\,dx$ converges only if $1 <a<2$.

Indeed for convergence at $x\to+\infty$ we need $a>1$, whereas the convergence at $x\to0$ requires $a<2$.

Comment: I got $\int_0^\infty |f(x)g(x)|dx=\int_0^\infty e^{\sin{x}}|\sin{2x}|x^{-a}dx\geq \int_0^\infty e^{\sin{x}}|\sin{2x}|^2x^{-a}dx=\int_0^\infty x^{-a}e^{\sin{x}}dx-\int_0^\infty x^{-a}e^{\sin{x}}\cos{4x}dx$. First integral diverges for every a and second converges for 0<a<2, therefore integral diverges. What am I missing? I couldnt get $a\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your approach. You need just to split the integral in two parts, e.g. $[0,\pi/2]$ and $[\pi/2,+\infty] $. Both integrals have to converge. In the first integral the integrand behaves like $2x^{1-a}$ as $x\to0$. In the second integral the integrand can be majorated by $e/x^a $.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{\sin{x}}\sin{2x}}{x^a}dx=2^{a-1}\int_2^\infty \frac{e^{\sin{(t/2)}}\sin{t}}{t^a}dt$$
For investigation of the convergence of the integral, it suffices to consider
$$I(a)=\int_{2\pi}^\infty \frac{e^{\sin{(t/2)}}\sin{t}}{t^a}dt=\int_{2\pi}^{4\pi}+\int_{4\pi}^{6\pi}+ ...$$
Due to periodicity of $\sin t$ we can write
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Bigl(\frac{e^{\sin{((t+2\pi)/2)}}}{(t+2\pi)^a}+\frac{e^{\sin{((t+4\pi)/2)}}}{(t+4\pi)^a} + ...\Bigr)\sin t \,dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin t \,dt\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{e^{\sin{(t/2+n\pi)}}}{(t+2\pi n)^a}-\frac{e^{\sin{(t/2+n\pi+\pi/2)}}}{(t+2\pi n+\pi)^a}\Bigr)$$
$$=4\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin (t/2)\cos(t/2) \,d(t/2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{e^{\sin{(t/2+n\pi)}}}{(t+2\pi n)^a}-\frac{e^{\cos{(t/2+n\pi)}}}{(t+2\pi n+\pi)^a}\Bigr)$$
$$=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin x\cos x \,dx\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{e^{\sin{(x+n\pi)}}}{(2x+2\pi n)^a}-\frac{e^{\cos{(x+n\pi)}}}{(2x+2\pi n+\pi)^a}\Bigr)$$

Making change in the second term $x\to\pi/2-x$ we can write
$$I(a)=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin x\cos x \,dx\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{\sin{(x+n\pi)}}\Bigl(\frac{1}{(2x+2\pi n)^a}-\frac{1}{(\pi-2x+2\pi n+\pi)^a}\Bigr)$$
$$I(a)=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin x\cos x \,dx\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{(-1)^n\sin x}a_n$$

where $a_n=\frac{1}{(2x+2\pi n)^a}-\frac{1}{(\pi-2x+2\pi n+\pi)^a}$ is positive.
Let's evaluate $a_n$

On the one hand,
$$a_n=\frac{(2\pi-2x+2\pi n)^a-(2x+2\pi n)^a}{(2x+2\pi n)^a(2\pi-2x+2\pi n)^a}>\frac{\Bigl(1+\frac{2\pi-4x}{2\pi +2\pi n}\Bigr)^a-1}{(2\pi+2\pi n)^{a}}$$
But for $\alpha<1$ and $a\in(0,1) \,\, (1+\alpha)^a<1+\alpha a\,$ (the function $(1+\alpha)^a$ is convex on the interval $(0,1)$ and equal to $1+\alpha a\,$ at $a=0,1$)
$$a_n>\frac{2\pi-4x}{2\pi(n+1)}\frac{a}{(2\pi(n+1))^a}=(2\pi-4x)\frac{a}{(2\pi)^{a+1}}\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}\bigl(1-O(1/n)\bigr)$$

On the other hand in the same way we can show that
$$a_n<(2\pi-4x)\frac{a}{(2\pi)^{a+1}}\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}$$

It means that the series (and, therefore, $I(a)$) converges at any $a>0$.

For $n\to \infty$
$$I(a)\sim\sum_{n} b_n\,\text {, where}\, b_n\sim \frac{8a}{(2\pi)^{a+1}}\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{(-1)^n\sin x}\sin x\cos x(\pi-2x)\,dx$$